# Printing a content pane with Printer, Email and PDF versions Module

Tags: theming, panels

I'm trying to determine how to add a content pane with an argument to a custom tpl.php file that is adding some other things to the print version.  I've done this before with a block, adding in the region that I needed to print out with the block, but in this case I don't think I can just print out "content_bottom" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Example code taken from [Programmatically display panels page](http://drupal.org/node/653584)

```
$node = node_load(array('type' => 'panel', 'title' =>'Your Node Page Title'));
$panel_node=node_view($node, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
print($panel_node);
```

Comment: I seem to remember trying this at some point, but the awkward environment makes it difficult to troubleshoot.  At the end of the day I guess I just don't know enough to make this work.

The way this appears to reference what it needs to load is the 'title', and I tried 'title' => $print['title'] but I have no idea of knowing if that's the "title" I need.

Since its a content pane with an argument I'm just not certain what its expecting there.